# Using IV with Diff-in-Diff Model in Stata

Tags: stata, instrumental-variables, difference-in-difference

For my data analysis, I am estimating a difference-in-difference model of the sort: `Y = a + bPOST + cTREAT + dPOST##TREAT +eCONTROLS + u`
Since I am concerned with the endogeneity of my treatment variable TREAT, I would like to employ an IV strategy, as the relevant literature suggests.

However, I am not sure how to run the IV regression in Stata, given that TREAT is part of an interaction term. I do not think the following code gives me the correct result:

`ivreg 2sls Y POST (TREAT = Z1)  POST##TREAT CONTROLS`

What is the right way of going about this?
Many thanks in advance.

(Please note that I am cross-posting from Statalist where I have not received an answer to this question so far (https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1604561-diff-in-diff-with-iv-for-treatment-dummy). Please let me know in case you need me to clarify anything!)